# return tuple of uncopyable objects

Tags: c++

consider the following:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

const auto length_of_file = [](auto & file){
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::streampos length = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    return length;
};

int main(int, char * []) {
    const auto check_and_read = [](const auto & filename){
        std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
        file.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
        std::vector<std::byte> data(length_of_file(file));
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data.data()), data.size());
        return std::make_tuple(file, data);
    };
    auto [file, data] = check_and_read("foo.txt");
}
```

This doesn’t compile because it wants to copy `file` which isn’t possible.

`return std::make_tuple(std::move(file), data);` works, but then i’m asking myself »Does this mean it’s copying instead of moving `data` now?«, so i would rather have a generic solution for this.

But neither (expecting move semantics/copy elision to kick in at least here):

```
const auto check_and_read = [](const auto & filename)
-> std::tuple<std::ifstream, std::vector<std::byte>> {

…

return {file, data}
```

nor (shouldn’t this move construct from a tuple of rvalue references?)

```
const auto check_and_read = [](const auto & filename)
-> std::tuple<std::ifstream, std::vector<std::byte>> {

…

return std::forward_as_tuple(file, data);
```

seems to work.

Is there some standard way to ensure move construction on return of multiple arguments without having to `std::move` each one individually?

Comment: I don't think so - seems like the standard way is to specify `std::move()` for each argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
std::tuple<std::string, std::string> foo() {
  std::string a = "hello";

  return {a, a};
}
```

The fact that your usage of `file` and `data` in your specific expressions is implicitely safely movable does not mean that it's always the case, even for very similar expressions.

The compiler has to be CERTAIN that the named identifier is doomed in order to treat it as a r-value, and such an analysis would quickly become unreasonably complex.

Comment: Good point, i didn’t consider this at all. Although it can be easily checked if arguments are duplicated, the bigger problem is that some arguments could be a part of another one.

Answer (score 7):

There's no standard function, but this should work (C++17):

```
template <class... Types>
auto move_to_tuple(Types&&... args) {
    return std::make_tuple(std::move(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Moves are never performed implicitly, except as a fallback in cases where elision is normally considered but happens to not be possible. Currently (well, at least to the best of my knowledge,) this means implicit moves only happen as fallbacks for RVO and NRVO.

Elision will never be considered for `file` and `data`. Neither RVO nor NRVO would apply to them to begin with. It is only considered for the returned tuple, because it's RVO in this case. Thus:

```
return std::make_tuple(std::move(file), data);
```

will elide the tuple through RVO, move the file and copy the data. So you should do:

```
return std::make_tuple(std::move(file), std::move(data));
```